# XPath as a string variable / property

Tags: xpath, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I retrieve XPath from a database (via DSS) and I need to apply it to the body. Is this somehow possible?

To give an example, let's say I have this xml request

```
<custom>
    <id>24</id>
    <text>Some Text</text>
    <firstOccurId>123456</firstOccurId>
    <secondOccurId>654321</secondOccurId>
</custom>
```

I take ID (24) and call template, which will return

```
<replacements>
    <row>
        <value>ABCDEFG</value>
        <xpath>/*/custom/firstOccurId</xpath>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>GFEDCDBA</value>
        <xpath>/*/custom/secondOccurId</xpath>
    </row>
</replacements>
```

now I need to apply xpath to request and change it's value, so the transformed request body looks like this

```
<custom>
    <id>24</id>
    <text>Some Text</text>
    <firstOccurId>ABCDEFG</firstOccurId>
    <secondOccurId>GFEDCDBA</secondOccurId>
</custom>
```

I tried both evaluate() and put XPath string inside {{}} in Call Template mediator, but both without success.

Comment: The `evaluate(..)` function would need an XSLT-3.0 processor like the commercial version of Saxon 9. Providing an alternative to this commercial version would need much more information than what you provided - if it's even possible.

Comment: WSO2 EI does have evaluate(), but to be honest, I don't know, what it exactly does.

Comment: AFAIK `evaluate(...)` treats a parameter as it would be an XPath expression.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works now, it was an issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate()` is the correct answer. To be more specific, for this example I need to store `custom` request in property, get `replacements`, loop through them and inside this loop I need to store full xpath in property as `fn:concat('$body', //el:row/el:xpath, '/text()')`, enrich body with original payload and apply stored xpath as `evaluate()`